# Segmentation fault using OpenMp and SSE

Tags: c, gcc, openmp, sse

I'm just getting started experimenting adding OpenMP to some SSE code.

My first test program SOMETIMES crashes in _mm_set_ps, but works when I set the if (0).

It looks so simple I must be missing something obvious. 
I'm compiling with gcc -fopenmp -g -march=core2 -pthreads

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <immintrin.h>

  int main()
  {
  #pragma omp parallel if (1)
   {
  #pragma omp sections
       {
  #pragma omp section
           {
              __m128 x1 = _mm_set_ps ( 1.1f, 2.1f, 3.1f, 4.1f );
           }
  #pragma omp section
           {
              __m128 x2 = _mm_set_ps ( 1.2f, 2.2f, 3.2f, 4.2f );
           }
       } // end omp sections
   } //end omp parallel

  return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in the openMP implementation. I was having the same problem in gcc on Windows (MinGW). [`-mstackrealign`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html#index-mstackrealign-1357) command line option solved my problem. This adds an instruction to the prolog of every function to realign the stack at the 16-byte boundary. I didn't notice any performance penalty. You can also try to add [`__attribute__ ((force_align_arg_pointer))`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) to a function declaration, which should do the same, but only for a specific function. You might have to put the SSE code in a separate function that you then call from the function with #pragma omp, so that the stack has a chance to be realigned.

I stopped having the problem when I moved onto compiling for a 64-bit target (MinGW64, such as [TDM GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) build).

I am playing with AVX instructions which require a 32-byte alignment, but GCC doesn't support that for windows at all. This forced me to fix the produced assembly code using a python script, but it works.

Comment: Using -mstackrealign seems to have resolved the issue. And if there is a performance penalty, it's still better than no performance! I'll see how it goes with some more complex code. Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, I don't have a 64-bit machine to play, with. I do have a AVX pc, so it's a shame that gcc doesn't support that yet.

Comment: To be precise, gcc supports AVX, including Core i7 2nd gen (Sandy Bridge), and from what I read online it works great on linux. But I've been having plenty of segmentation fault problems on Windows with MinGW64, so it will probably a MinGW related bug. But I might be just doing something wrong...

Comment: The g++ option `-mstackrealign` worked perfectly. For the alternative, in my case I also had to add the `noinline` attribute to make sure the function call was there in the first place: `__attribute__((force_align_arg_pointer,noinline))`

Answer (score 2):

I smell unaligned memory access. Its the only way code like that could explode(assuming that *is* the only code there). For that to happen the XMM registers wouldn't be used but rather stack memory, which is only aligned to 4 bytes, my guess is the omp code is messing up the alignment of the stack.